# Passing 2d array from server

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to pass a 2d array from my `server.js` to `client.js` but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. When I click the button to display grid nothing happens. Here is my array on the server side:

```
var ar = Array(2);

for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
   ar[i]=Array(2);

 }
       ar[0][0]='one';
       ar[1][0]='two';
       ar[0][1]='three';
       ar[1][1]='four';

    var theTable = "";
      for(var j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
          theTable += '<tr>';
          for(var k=0;k<2;k++){             
            theTable += '<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>';
          }
          theTable += '</tr>';
      }

app.post("/postScores", function(req , res){ 
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.write(theTable);
  res.end();

 });
```

Then on the client side I am trying to retrieve the table from the server like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#show").on('click', function(){

      $.post('/postScores', function(scores){

      $("#grid").append(scores);


    });      
   });  

 });
```

Comment: Why do you write HTML code in the server side? Pass only the data from the server (for example with `res.json(ar)`) then build the HTML client side

Comment: So essentially just build theTable on client side? and store ar on the server?